# Python - Create string with for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, concatenation

As a beginner to Python I got these tasks by the teacher to finish and I'm stuck on one of them. It's about finding the consonants in a word using a for-loop and then create a string with those consonants.

The code I have is:

```
consonants = ["qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm"]
summer_word = "icecream"

new_word = ""

for consonants in summer_word:
    new_word += consonants

ANSWER = new_word
```

The for-loop I get but it's the concatenation I don't really get. If I use `new_word = []` it becomes a list, so I should use the `""`? It should become a string if you concatenate a number of strings or characters, right? If you have an int you have to use `str(int)` in order to concatenate that as well.
But, how do I create this string of consonants? I think my code is sound but it doesn't play out.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is currently just looping through the characters of summer_word. The name "consonants" you give in "for consonants..." is just a dummy variable, it doesn't actually reference consonants that you defined. Try something like this:

```
consonants = "qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm" # This is fine don't need a list of a string.
summer_word = "icecream"

new_word = ""

for character in summer_word: # loop through each character in summer_word
    if character in consonants: # check whether the character is in the consonants list
        new_word += character
    else:
        continue # Not really necessary by adds structure. Just says do nothing if it isn't a consonant.

ANSWER = new_word
```

Answer (score 1):

A string in Python is already a list of characters and may be treated as such:

```
In [3]: consonants = "qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm"

In [4]: summer_word = "icecream"

In [5]: new_word = ""

In [6]: for i in summer_word:
   ...:     if i in consonants:
   ...:         new_word += i
   ...:

In [7]: new_word
Out[7]: 'ccrm'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, if the character is a number you must use str(int) to convert it in string type.

```
consonants = ["qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm"]
summer_word = "icecream"

new_word = ""
vowels = 'aeiou'
for consonants in summer_word:
    if consonants.lower() not in vowels and type(consonants) != int:
        new_word += consonants
answer = new_word
```

Here inside the for loop you are evaluating if the 'consonants' is not a vowel and is not an int. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have here is that you have created the variable consonants as a list with a string in it. So remove the square brackets and it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
consonants = "qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm"
summer_word = "icecream"

new_word = ""


for letter in summer_word:
    if letter in consonants:
      new_word += letter

print(new_word)
```

A shorter one would be

```
consonants = "qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm"
summer_word = "icecream"

new_word = ""

new_word = [l for l in summer_word if l in consonants]
print("".join(new_word))
```